# C# RestSharp v107 -> How use DeserializationAs

Tags: c#, json, rest, deserialization, restsharp

i woudl like to upgrade RestSharp Nuget from 106 to 107 version.
In 106 version i using RestSharp.Deserializers namespace and tag like below

```
[DeserializeAs(Name = "testinfo")]
public string Testinfo{ get; set; }
```

In version 107 this is no longer used,
does anyone know how to keep the same functionality in the newer version

Comment: I had the same question but I clearly didn't see it in the documentation. but I think the answer below works

Answer (score 1):

If you use JSON, the documentation [clearly mentions](https://restsharp.dev/serialization.html#json) that the default serializer for v107 is System.Text.Json.

The serializer [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0) is available, so you should get all the information you need there.

In particular, you can override the property name by using the `JsonPropertyName` attribute, as described on the docs page I mentioned just above.